# 404 handling when 404 page is overwritten in apache

Tags: php, javascript, apache, http-status-code-404

I am working on a website where I have configured apache to point the *404* page to `index.php` via:

```
"ErrorDocument 404 /index.php"
```

so i can parse the url arguments manually. I am currently writing an image wrapper so if you go to for example

```
"myssite.com/image/test"
```

it will display a test image with the the *php* header set to image/jpeg in-order to mask the images physical location on the server as images will later be managed by a database. when I display this image via *php* like so:

```
"echo '<img src="/image/test" alt="some_text">';"
```

It is displayed correctly. if this same thing is done with javascript and inserted onto the page, It receives a 404 error and does not load the image.

I figure I either need to make `apache` not report a **404** at all, or somehow change the way javascript handles it. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could also use the commonplace RewriteRule to redirect non-existent request paths. Or use an appropriate header() call in your handler script to override the 404.

Comment: Is there a way to use RewriteRule to ignore all possible url arguments without throwing 404? The header changes based on what content you are accessing on the site. such as anything from /image/ will have an image header vs something from /content/ for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 404 error was fixed by adding the following to httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]

</Directory>
```

Although that did not help with the image not being displayed, which caused me to to look closer at the function displaying the image. Something is going bad when I use a cropping script prior to the image displaying causing more than likely an issue with the header. this should require minor back-end changes on my part.

thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

please connect your page with an other php script to understand header response

> ```
> $ch = curl_init('http://myssite.com/image/test'); 
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
> $data = curl_exec($ch);
> echo $data;
> ```

be sure it gives 200 ok;

if it gives 404 may be the problem is header.

so you must to use htaccess redirection to your images